# How to check if identifier existed in previous months list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to determine, if an identifier occurs first in a given month (i.e. it is 'new' to the list of identifier). Below, there is the first attempt, but it flags identifier `a3` as old on 28 Feb 2020, although it was not in the list on 31 Jan 2020.

Note that this is a simplified example: in practice, I would have more group by columns, not just date, and I would need to check, if the identifier is new to the 'cell' created by the combination of date, industry, age, etc. There could be many.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

data = """
date                            identifier     value
 31-Dec-2019                    a1   10
 31-Dec-2019                    a2   20
 31-Dec-2019                    a3   30
 31-Jan-2020                    a1   40
 31-Jan-2020                    a2   50
 31-Jan-2020                    a4   60
 31-Jan-2020                    a5   60
 28-Feb-2020                    a1   70
 28-Feb-2020                    a4   80
 28-Feb-2020                    a3   90
"""

res=[]
for row in [el.split() for el in data.splitlines()][1:]:
    rrow=[]
    for col in row:
        try:
            if float(col):
                col = np.float32(col)
        except:
            pass
        rrow.append(col)
    res.append(rrow)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=res[1:], columns=res[0])

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.set_index(["date", "identifier"]).sort_index()

df["valprev"] = df.groupby(level="identifier")["value"].shift(1)
df["isnew"] = df.valprev.isnull(
```

[image]

Comment: Do we have to just check (`single previous month` or `all the previous months`) for identifier's occurrence?

Comment: only the single previous month

Comment: Are the dates always sorted and appear consecutively with the gap of one month?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) convert the `date` column to pandas `datetime` series:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

**Then use:**

```
s1 = df.groupby('date')['identifier'].value_counts()
s2 = s1.unstack().diff().replace({0: False, np.nan: True}).stack()
df['isnew'] = df.set_index(['date', 'identifier']).index.map(s2)
```

---

**Details:**

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `date` and aggregate the column `identifier` using [`Groupby.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
# print(s1):

date        identifier
2019-12-31  a1            1
            a2            1
            a3            1
2020-01-31  a1            1
            a2            1
            a4            1
            a5            1
2020-02-28  a1            1
            a3            1
            a4            1
Name: identifier, dtype: int64
```

Use [`Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) on series `s1` to `reshape` it, then use [`DataFrame.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to calculate successive differences between counts of identifier, this step will help in identifying the occurrence of `repeated` identifiers from `previous month`, next use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to again convert it into `MultiLevel` index series named `s2`.

```
# s1.unstack().diff()
identifier   a1   a2  a3   a4  a5
date                             
2019-12-31  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN
2020-01-31  0.0  0.0 NaN  NaN NaN
2020-02-28  0.0  NaN NaN  0.0 NaN

# print(s2) # this series will be use to map in next step
date        identifier
2019-12-31  a1             True
            a2             True
            a3             True
            a4             True
            a5             True
2020-01-31  a1            False
            a2            False
            a3             True
            a4             True
            a5             True
2020-02-28  a1            False
            a2             True
            a3             True
            a4            False
            a5             True
dtype: bool
```

Use `set_index` to set the index of dataframe `df` as `date` and `identifier` and use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map this index from the values from `s2`, assign this mapped value to the new column `isnew`:

```
# print(df)
        date identifier  value  isnew
0 2019-12-31         a1     10   True
1 2019-12-31         a2     20   True
2 2019-12-31         a3     30   True
3 2020-01-31         a1     40  False
4 2020-01-31         a2     50  False
5 2020-01-31         a4     60   True
6 2020-01-31         a5     60   True
7 2020-02-28         a1     70  False
8 2020-02-28         a4     80  False
9 2020-02-28         a3     90   True
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can make a new data frame with previous month values:

```
>>> prev_identifiers = df\
...     .groupby(['date'])\
...     .identifier.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))\
...     .shift(1)\
...     .fillna('')\
...     .reset_index()\
...     .rename({'identifier': 'identifier_prev'}, axis=1)
>>> print(prev_identifiers)
        date identifier_prev
0 2019-12-31                
1 2020-01-31        a1,a2,a3
2 2020-02-28     a1,a2,a4,a5
```

After that you can merge `df` and `prev_identifiers` together and decide, if current identifier is, or is not in previous identifiers list:

```
>>> df = pd.merge(df, prev_identifiers, how='left', on='date')
>>> df['is_new'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['identifier'] not in row['identifier_prev'], axis=1)
>>> print(df)
        date identifier value identifier_prev  is_new
0 2019-12-31         a1    10                    True
1 2019-12-31         a2    20                    True
2 2019-12-31         a3    30                    True
3 2020-01-31         a1    40        a1,a2,a3   False
4 2020-01-31         a2    50        a1,a2,a3   False
5 2020-01-31         a4    60        a1,a2,a3    True
6 2020-01-31         a5    60        a1,a2,a3    True
7 2020-02-28         a1    70     a1,a2,a4,a5   False
8 2020-02-28         a4    80     a1,a2,a4,a5   False
9 2020-02-28         a3    90     a1,a2,a4,a5    True
```